# What's the difference between the ring of Integers and the maximal order in a Number field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have faced the concept of maximal order, while reading one of the books of Goro Shimura, Euler Products and Eisenstein Series.

I am familiar with the concept of ring of integers of a number field. I have read something on the orders and lattices, but its confused me.

So at first, I prefer to fix some definitions to reduce my confusion.
Let $\mathbf{F}$ be a number field, i.e. a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $n$ to be the degree of this extension, i.e. $n:=[\mathbf{F}:\mathbb{Q}]$, also we denote by $\mathfrak{O}_{\mathbf{F}}$ the ring of integers of $\mathbf{F}$.

By an **order** $\mathfrak{O}$ in $\mathbf{F}$ we mean a subring of $\mathfrak{O}_{\mathbf{F}}$, which has the $\mathbb{Z}$-dimension equal to $n$.

Are all of my definitions are right, Specially the definition of an **order**?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(ring_theory).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that is the definition of an order in a number field. And indeed
in a number field, the ring of integers is the unique maximal order.

Comment: Sorry, and one more another question, what's does we mean by a ***Lattic**, and what is it's relation with the concept of order?

Comment: @Famke In this context, a lattice is just a finitely generated Abelian group; an isomorph of $\Bbb Z^n$. So the ring of integers of $F$ is a lattice, and so are its nonzero ideals and fractional ideals.